# How can I show all models in one index page and order them by "created_at DESC"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Posts Model, and a Projects Model. I want to render both of these on one index page and order them by `created_at DESC`. How can I do this? Thanks in advance...

Comment: check out [rails admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separately?

```
<% Post.order('created_at DESC').each do |post| %>
  #do things
<% end %>

<% Project.order('created_at DESC').each do |project| %>
  #do things
<% end %>
```

Together?

```
<% (Post.all + Project.all).sort_by{|item| -item.created_at}.each do |item| %>
  <% if item.is_a? Post %>
    <%= render 'post_partial', post: item %>
  <% elsif item.is_a? Project %>
    <%= render 'project_partial', project: item %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Then create a partial for both objects, and use your attributes as needed!

Comment: My projects model and my posts model have different attributes.... so `item.headline` for example will only work on posts and then throw an error with projects. It would some how have to be ordered after the iteration.

Comment: Put it in a controller @XMLSlayer.

Comment: @SebastiánPalma Yes of course, but for simplicity sake it was easier to explain like this